# Oracle aq propagation, ORA-25215: user_data type and queue type do not match

Tags: database, oracle, types, oracle11g, advanced-queuing

I am working on AQ propagation from one database to another, however when i scheduled a propagation and enqueued first message to LOCAL AQ table i've got an error in DBA_QUEUE_SCHEDULES.LAST_ERROR_MSG, "ORA-25215: user_data type and queue type do not match". Note that both object types used in AQ tables is identical, for test purpose i'm using this one:

```
create or replace type LOCAL_OBJ_MSG as object(
    test varchar2(4000))
/
```

and both AQ tables are also identical, i've created them using same scripts and only changed names, one LOCAL other REMOTE. LOCAL AQ table is in LOCAL database, REMOTE one is in SCHEMA_NAME.REMOTE database.

Here's scripts i've used to create AQ tables:

```
declare
  QUEUE_NOT_FOUND exception;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(QUEUE_NOT_FOUND, -24010);
begin
  dbms_aqadm.stop_queue(
    queue_name => 'REMOTE_iTEST');
exception
  when QUEUE_NOT_FOUND then
    null;
  when others then
    raise;
end;
/

declare
  QUEUE_NOT_FOUND exception;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(QUEUE_NOT_FOUND, -24010);
begin
  dbms_aqadm.drop_queue('REMOTE_iTEST');
exception
  when QUEUE_NOT_FOUND then
    null;
  when others then
    raise;
end;
/

declare
  QUEUE_NOT_FOUND exception;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(QUEUE_NOT_FOUND, -24002);
begin
  dbms_aqadm.drop_queue_table('REMOTE_iTEST', force => true);
exception
  when QUEUE_NOT_FOUND then
    null;
  when others then
    raise;
end;
/

declare
  QUEUE_NOT_FOUND exception;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(QUEUE_NOT_FOUND, -24010);
begin
  dbms_aqadm.stop_queue(
    queue_name => 'REMOTE_oTEST');
exception
  when QUEUE_NOT_FOUND then
    null;
  when others then
    raise;
end;
/

declare
  QUEUE_NOT_FOUND exception;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(QUEUE_NOT_FOUND, -24010);
begin
  dbms_aqadm.drop_queue('REMOTE_oTEST');
exception
  when QUEUE_NOT_FOUND then
    null;
  when others then
    raise;
end;
/

declare
  QUEUE_NOT_FOUND exception;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(QUEUE_NOT_FOUND, -24002);
begin
  dbms_aqadm.drop_queue_table('REMOTE_oTEST', force => true);
exception
  when QUEUE_NOT_FOUND then
    null;
  when others then
    raise;
end;
/

declare
  l_exist number;
  cursor c_index is
    select 1 from user_objects u where u.OBJECT_NAME = upper('LOCAL_OBJ_MSG') and u.OBJECT_TYPE = 'TYPE';
begin
  open c_index;
  fetch c_index into l_exist;
  close c_index;

  if l_exist = 1 then
    execute immediate 'drop type LOCAL_OBJ_MSG';
  end if;
end;
/

create or replace type LOCAL_OBJ_MSG as object(
    test varchar2(4000))    
/

begin
  dbms_aqadm.create_queue_table (
    queue_table => 'REMOTE_iTEST',
    queue_payload_type => 'LOCAL_OBJ_MSG',
    storage_clause => 'pctfree 5 pctused 90 tablespace SEPA_INTEG_AQ',
    message_grouping => DBMS_AQADM.NONE,
    sort_list => 'ENQ_TIME',
    multiple_consumers => true,
    comment => 'Incoming TEST message table.');
end;
/

begin
  dbms_aqadm.create_queue (
    queue_table    => 'REMOTE_iTEST',
    queue_name     => 'REMOTE_iTEST',
    queue_type => sys.dbms_aqadm.normal_queue,
    retention_time => sys.dbms_aqadm.INFINITE,
    comment => 'Incoming TEST messages.',
    max_retries => 5);
end;
/

begin
  dbms_aqadm.start_queue(
    queue_name  => 'REMOTE_iTEST',
    dequeue     => true,
    enqueue     => true);
end;
/
begin
  dbms_aqadm.create_queue_table (
    queue_table => 'REMOTE_oTEST',
    queue_payload_type => 'LOCAL_OBJ_MSG',
    storage_clause => 'pctfree 5 pctused 90 tablespace SEPA_INTEG_AQ',
    message_grouping => DBMS_AQADM.NONE,
    sort_list => 'ENQ_TIME',
    multiple_consumers => true,
    comment => 'Outgoing TEST message table.');
end;
/

begin
  dbms_aqadm.create_queue (
    queue_table    => 'REMOTE_oTEST',
    queue_name     => 'REMOTE_oTEST',
    queue_type => sys.dbms_aqadm.normal_queue,
    retention_time => sys.dbms_aqadm.INFINITE,
    comment => 'Outgoing TEST messages.',
    max_retries => 5);
end;
/

begin
  dbms_aqadm.start_queue(
    queue_name  => 'REMOTE_oTEST',
    dequeue     => TRUE,
    enqueue     => TRUE);
end;
/
```

And here's scripts used to create subscribers, dequeue procedures, etc.:

LOCAL db:

```
begin
  -- Add the remote subscriber.
  dbms_aqadm.add_subscriber(queue_name     => 'LOCAL_oTEST',
                            subscriber     => sys.aq$_agent(name     => 'LOCAL_oTEST_subscriber',
                                                            address  => 'SCHEMA_NAME.REMOTE_oTEST@DB_LINK_NAME',
                                                            protocol => 0),
                            queue_to_queue => true);
  -- Start the propagation of messages.
  dbms_aqadm.schedule_propagation(queue_name        => 'LOCAL_oTEST',
                                  latency           => 0,
                                  destination       => 'DB_LINK_NAME',
                                  destination_queue => 'SCHEMA_NAME.REMOTE_oTEST');
end;
/
```

REMOTE db:

```
-- Create a table to store the messages received.
create table sepa_omsg_aq_demo
  (received timestamp default systimestamp,
   message LOCAL_OBJ_MSG);

-- Create a callback procedure that dequeues the received message and saves it
create or replace
procedure REMOTE_CALLBACK_TEST
  (
    context raw,
    reginfo sys.aq$_reg_info,
    descr sys.aq$_descriptor,
    payload raw,
    payloadl number
  )
as
  r_dequeue_options dbms_aq.dequeue_options_t;
  r_message_properties dbms_aq.message_properties_t;
  v_message_handle raw(26);
  o_payload LOCAL_OBJ_MSG;
begin
  r_dequeue_options.msgid         := descr.msg_id;
  r_dequeue_options.consumer_name := descr.consumer_name;
  dbms_aq.dequeue(queue_name => descr.queue_name, 
                  dequeue_options => r_dequeue_options, 
                  message_properties => r_message_properties, 
                  payload => o_payload, 
                  msgid => v_message_handle);
  insert into sepa_omsg_aq_demo 
    (message) 
    values (o_payload);
  commit;
exception
  when others then
    rollback;
end;
/

-- Register the procedure for dequeuing the messages received.
-- I'd like to point out that the subscriber is the one defined for the local database
begin
  dbms_aq.register (
     sys.aq$_reg_info_list(
        sys.aq$_reg_info('REMOTE_oTEST:LOCAL_oTEST_subscriber',
                         dbms_aq.namespace_aq,
                         'plsql://REMOTE_CALLBACK_TEST',
                         hextoraw('FF'))
                        ), 
        1);
end;
/
```

Sript to enqueue messages to LOCAL AQ table:

```
declare
  enq_msgid raw(16);
  eopt      dbms_aq.enqueue_options_t;
  mprop     dbms_aq.message_properties_t;

  message local_obj_msg;
begin
  message := local_obj_msg('a');
  dbms_aq.enqueue(queue_name         => 'LOCAL_oTEST',
                  enqueue_options    => eopt,
                  message_properties => mprop,
                  payload            => message,
                  msgid              => enq_msgid);
  commit;
end;
/
```

Also note that in SYS.AQ$_MESSAGE_TYPES table(LOCAL db), verified status = 'F' for created propagation, and:

```
declare
  rc binary_integer;
begin
  dbms_aqadm.verify_queue_types(src_queue_name  => 'local_otest',
                                dest_queue_name => 'schema_name.remote_otest',
                                rc              => rc,
                                destination     => 'db_link_name');
  dbms_output.put_line('Compatible: ' || rc);
end;
/
```

returns 0, which means that table types aren't compatible. After i did some diging i've found that remote propagation cannot be done if LOCAL and REMOTE database NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS differ, however in this situation it's not the case. i've checked. Any idea's what i'm doing wrong or how can i find what differs between these two tables and how to fix it? Or maybe it can be a difference between some DB parameter value?

Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One area to check is the NLS_LENGHT_SEMANTICS parameter value on each database.

> ***[NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24693_01/server.11203/e24448/initparams149.htm)*** allows you to specify the length of a column
>   datatype in terms of characters rather in terms of bytes.

Your PL/SQL Type creation script does not implicitly use BYTE or CHAR conversion within the VARCHAR2 length. This will cause generation of the type to inherit the value as set for *NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS*.

Make sure you check your two database NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS value. in the event the values are different (BYTE vs CHAR) it could be the cause of the issue. You can either rebuild the type and queue on one of the database by explicitly using the BYTE or CHAR in the VARCHAR2
i.e

```
create or replace type LOCAL_OBJ_MSG as object(
    test varchar2(4000 CHAR))
/
```

or change the *NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS* on one of the database to make sure they match. It is important to recompile the database after changing *NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however in both databases NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS is set to CHAR.

Comment: I have executed the scripts you provided on two Oracle 11.2.0.3.0 successfully. Enqueing the message works fine without any issues and the message is propagated to the remote queue. I know it might sound obvious but visiting NLS subject, can you verify these are identical for your dbs? `select * from nls_database_parameters Where parameter = 'NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS';
select * from nls_instance_parameters Where parameter = 'NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS';
select * from nls_session_parameters Where parameter = 'NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS';`

Comment: Yes, they differ. In remote i have CHAR, CHAR, CHAR in LOCAL, BYTE, CHAR, CHAR. Previously i've checked in v$parameter and it was the same, didn't know about these views. So now i need to recreate my remote object as ...varchar2(4000 CHAR))...?

Comment: I wasn't expecting the first one to differ to be honest :). The database nls setting is by default set to BYTE (This is for oracle database objects to be installed with BYTE). I was expecting the other two to have differences. If the nls database level parameter was changed prior creating the db you are working on the issue might be deeper. `DBMS_AQADM.verify_queue_types` seems to log errors in `sys.aq$_message_types`. Can you check if anything is populated in that table after you execute the verification procedure?

Comment: Yes, record appears with "sys.aq$_message_types.verified = 'F'".

Comment: There seems to be a guidance from oracle not to change nls_length_semantics at the [database level] (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24693_01/server.11203/e24448/initparams149.htm) as it could cause unexpected behaviour. I am not sure whether this could be the root cause of the issue you are facing. Rebuilding the type as `VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)` will not guarantee it will fix your issue but you could try.

Comment: Yeah, it didn't fix the issue. Just to be sure, i've created another propagation on database in which nls_length_semantics is the same and it worked. If i find a workaround on this i'll post it. I have another question, what's the difference between nls_length_sematics parameter in v$parameter view and nls_database_parameter view?

Comment: From oracle documentation [link] (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_5122.htm) `nls_database_parameters` lists permanent NLS parameters of the database. `v$parameter` as an oracle dynamic view displays current value of the specified parameter within your session.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this a little late, but we have a workaround for this. In propagation between two databases, which has different semantics you cannot use object type as payload, however you can specify a transformation on propagation of that object type to xmltype, which can be propagated. To do that you will need temp, or not, queueu in remote database which will receive that xmltype. Then you can have a scheduler job, which will periodically dequeue messages from that queue and enqueue it further to your remote destination queue. On dequeue you can specify another transformation which will transform your xmltype payload to desired object type. Below is and example:

Lets say we have object type:

```
create or replace type OBJ_MSG as object(
    id number,
    value varchar2(4000)
)
```

Which we'll use in our local and remote databases. Next step is to have a remote queue with payload as xmltype. Next we need transformation function, which takes our OBJ_MSG object type as parameter and returns xmltype.

```
function trans_to_xml_type(
  p_payload in OBJ_MSG)
  return xmltype is

  cursor c_trans_payload(
    cp_id number,
    cp_value varchar2) is
  select
    xmlelement(
      "envelope",
      xmlelement(
        "id", cp_client),
      xmlelement(
        "value", cp_value))
  from
    dual;

  l_return xmltype;
begin
  open c_trans_payload(
    p_payload.id,
    p_payload.value);
  fetch c_trans_payload
    into l_return;
  close c_trans_payload;

  return l_return;

  exception
    when others then
      raise_application_error(-20001, '.trans_to_xml_type .Failed to transform OBJ_MSG payload to sys.xmltype: ' || sqlerrm);
end;
```

Next, we create our transformation:

```
begin
  dbms_transform.create_transformation(
    'LOCAL',--SCHEMA
    'LOCAL_TRANS_TO_XML_TYPE',--Our transformation name
    'LOCAL',--SCHEMA
    'OBJ_MSG',--Our object name
    'SYS',
    'XMLTYPE',--Transformation result
    'PACKAGE.trans_to_xml_type(source.user_data)');--function name, which takes payload as a parameter
end;
/
```

Next we create a subsriber with our transformation and add it to queueu:

```
declare
  l_agent sys.aq$_agent := sys.aq$_agent(
    name => 'local_agent',
    address => 'REMOTE.REMOTE_TEMP_QUEUE@REMOTE_DB',
    protocol => 0);
begin
  dbms_aqadm.add_subscriber(
    queue_name => 'LOCAL.LOCAL_QUEUE',
    subscriber => l_agent,
    transformation => 'LOCAL_TRANS_TO_XML_TYPE',
    queue_to_queue => true);
end;
/
```

So now we schedule propagation to our temp queue. Object types of propagated messages will be converted to xmltype and enqueued to our remote temp queue. In remote DB create a dbms_scheduler job which will periodically dequeue messages, with specified transformation and enqueue it to remote destination queue.